# swipe to dismiss listview item like viewpager

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, swipe-gesture

I am using [this](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo) to dismiss listview item. There is a problem with this code.The undo view is also swipable which i dont want.Moreover as soon as the listview item is swiped to display undo view it should get removed from the listview.I canot think of how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try any other library.

Comment: didnot find anything matching my requirement